# Book mark issue in iframe

Tags: html, extjs, bookmarks

I am using ext js 4.2 and i am rendering the HTML in iframe. The issue which i am facing is that in HTML content we have some bookmarks and when i clicked (back to top) it refresh the page instead go to top. To test the case i copied the HTML content in another file and open in IE and its working fine but not in iframe. Can any one help me on this issue how to resolve so book marks can work in iframe too.

[image]

Comment: Any solution for above query ??

Comment: I have replaced book mark with onclick=window.scrollTo(0,0); and it works